# Zoom audio fixed to an HDMI output and muted

Tags: sound, xubuntu, headphones, zoom-meeting

Yesterday I installed Xubuntu 20.04 in an HP ProBook 430 G7. Today I joined a Zoom meeting and cannot hear the audio, no matter what I try. As can be seen in the pictures below, the Zoom stream "has sound" (the orange bar moves as people speaks) and it is directed to the HDMI3/DP3 output (I don't exactly know what this is, why are there 3 HDMI audio outputs?). If I try to redirect the Zoom audio stream to the Speaker+Headphones (as is the Firefox stream, which works perfectly) it does nothing. I mean, if I click where the mouse is in picture 2, nothing happens. I have tried to unplug the HDMI screen, same result. I have tried to plug the headphones in the screen headphone connector, no audio at all there. Ideas?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally after some time I found that I can change this configuration within Zoom. It seems that Zoom locks itself to some audio output and the OS is not able to change it.

Answer (score 0):

After connecting the HDMI cable, on computer volume select your computer system e.g. Samsung  (Nvidia high definition audio)... Then in Zoom (by mic) go to select a speaker then click "same as system".